# r stargazer - add lines to regression output and costumise their order

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

My question falls somewhere between [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950517/add-a-row-with-notes-using-stargazer) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683646/r-stargazer-add-reference-categories).

I want to add a line in the regression output for the reference category of a factor variable. Stargazer doesn't seem to have an easy way of doing this. My current approach is to add a line with `add.lines` and then manually change the order of that new line, in my Word document. This is of course tedious.

```
x <- as.factor(c("a","b","c"))
x1 <- c(1,2,3)

# Estimate a model
m1 <- lm(x1~x)

#Create output
stargazer(m1, type = "text", style="ajs", add.lines=c("a (ref.)"))
```

This is where I stand now:

```
> stargazer(m1, type = "text", style="ajs", add.lines=c("a (ref.)"))


========================
                 X1     
------------------------
xb              1.000   


xc              2.000   


Constant        1.000   


a (ref.)                
Observations      3     
R2              1.000   
------------------------
Notes:       *P < .05   
             **P < .01  
             ***P < .001
```

My desired output is this:

```
========================
                 X1     
------------------------
a (ref.)                
   xb           1.000   


   xc           2.000   


Constant        1.000   


Observations      3     
R2              1.000   
------------------------
Notes:       *P < .05   
             **P < .01  
             ***P < .001
```

What's an automatic way of customising the order of an added line? Or, if you prefer, a more general question: What's an easy way of adding the reference category of factor variables in its correct order?

Comment: FYI, in this case the `Constant` **is** the coefficient for the reference category, so ordering it like you have might be confusing to say the least.

Comment: Good point. In my actual model I have many other variables, so the constant is not capturing only the reference value. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `table.layout` argument to customize your table layout:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1, type = "text", style="ajs", add.lines=c("a (ref.)"), table.layout = "=ldc-ats-n")
```

**Result:**

```
========================
                 X1     
------------------------
a (ref.)                
xb              1.000   


xc              2.000   


Constant        1.000   



Observations      3     
R2              1.000   
------------------------
Notes:       *P < .05   
             **P < .01  
             ***P < .001
```

**Note:**

`"=ldc-ats-n"` determines what elements and in what order they appear in the output, each character is an element. For instance, `"t"` represents "coefficient table" while `"a"` represents "additional lines", so placing `"a"` before `"t"` gives you the correct order. See `?stargazer` and go to `table.layout` for more details.